# Bcrypt with two different user models on rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

I have two migration tables: parents and teachers. And I use Bcrypt for registration. I can't figure out what I should do with log in and sessions_controller (sessions helper). I can register new user and when user registers he can only see Sign Out link in navbar. However, I can not sign out user, I am not sure how I define the methods in sessions controller and session helper. Maybe somebody can help me with this?
I can not find information about bcrypt with different user models - is this thing not popular or is this so easy and I am just stupid and do not understand a thing??

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

def new
end

def create
    teacher = Teacher.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
  parent = Parent.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
    if teacher && teacher.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        log_in teacher
        redirect_to documents_path
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome!"
  elsif parent && parent.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in parent
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:notice] = "Welcome!"
    else 
        flash[:alert] = "Please log in again!"
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    if log_out parent
    redirect_to root_path
elsif log_out teacher
  redirect_to root_path
end
end
end
```

And here is my sessions helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

# Logs in the given user.
 def log_in(parent)
  session[:parent_id] = parent.id
 end

 def log_in(teacher)
  session[:teacher_id] = teacher.id
 end

 # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_teacher
   @current_teacher ||= Teacher.find_by(id: session[:teacher_id])
  end

 def current_parent
  @current_parent ||= Parent.find_by(id: session[:parent_id])
 end

# Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
def logged_in?(teacher)
  !current_teacher.nil?
end

def logged_in?(parent)
 !current_parent.nil?
end

def log_out(teacher)
 session.delete(:teacher_id)
  @current_teacher = nil
end

def log_out(parent)
 session.delete(:parent_id)
  @current_parent = nil
end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of the your application, but I can explain the general case.

First of all, controller which has log in function is not have to be named `sessions_controller`, name is anything OK.

And Bcrypt is basically only a library for encrypting passwords. Main process is checking the password entered by user is valid or not without decrypting. There is no clear answer  how to implement controller logic.

Apparently, user is divided into two types, Teacher and Parent, and probably each has different functions. So essentially, I want to divide the two login processes into separate controllers or actions. Because each login process is not the same one.

But Teacher and Parent will log in with the same URL if user have to login from the same page due to the UI restriction. If you are in such circumstances, implementing in the same controller & action will be appropriate.

After all, it depends on how to design your application. So your code is not always wrong.

However, look at your code, Teacher or Parent is judged only by e-mail, it is doubtful whether this is a proper approach. I have not seen many websites where users with different privileges log in from the same page.

I think that it is basically divide the login page depending on Teacher or Parent. If you divide the login page, example is as follows.

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

  def login
  end

  def login_action
    teacher = Teacher.find_by(email: params[:teacher][:email])

    if teacher && teacher.authenticate(params[:teacher][:password])
      log_in teacher
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome!'

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Invalid log in information!'
      redirect_to action: :login
    end
  end

  def logout
    teacher = Teacher.find(session[:teacher_id])
    log_out teacher

    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

  def login
  end

  def login_action
    parent = Parent.find_by(email: params[:parent][:email])

    if parent && parent.authenticate(params[:parent][:password])
      log_in parent
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome!'

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Invalid log in information!'
      redirect_to action: :login
    end
  end

  def logout
    parent = Parent.find(session[:parent_id])
    log_out parent

    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Although this is not the main issue, did you write sessions_helper in the `helpers` directory?

Usually, helper is used to implement for view logic, so if you want to share method in controller, use `ActiveSupport::Concern` in the `concerns` directory.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer! Really helped me. I divided login page, also created sessions_controller  for each model and everything works just fine!